# Swift 4 hide view and fill the blank

Tags: xcode, swift4

I want to make the search bar disappear by clicking the navigation bar item and make the collection view to fill the blank, animated obviously. ( like making the screen move upwards because the keyboard is showing )

is it Possible also to make it disappear when I scroll down an appear when I scroll up again ?

I dont think both ways will work at the same time but anyway I want to know how to make each way work.

[image]

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

A collection view is a scroll view. A scroll view can have a delegate. A scroll view's delegate is told when the scroll view is scrolling. Therefore you can do anything you like in response to the user scrolling the scroll view, including moving the search bar.